# Xcode 4 plain C static library linking

Tags: c, xcode, static

I would like to build a plain C console app in `Xcode`. I have 5 source files added to a project and a library, say `libMyLib.a`. The C source files obviously use the library. I can't get this to work, the linker produces errors of type :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64...

I have checked with lipo that the static library supports this architecture. I tried various options suggested on this forum: setting paths to headers (absolute, as well as using `$(SOURCE_ROOT)`), setting Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries, using workspaces. The same source code compiles fine when using command line gcc. I have also tried setting additional linker flags in `Xcode` to those that I use with make. Nothing works. What am I missing?